# FluXCD Helm deployment from Azure ACR - no chart name found error

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, fluxcd

I am attempting to deploy a Helm chart to AKS using FluxCD. The chart has been pushed to Azure ACR using the Helm cli - "helm push ...". The chart is declared in the ACR as helm/release-services:0.1.0

I am receiving the following error after a Flux reconcile:

> 'chart pull error: failed to get chart version for remote reference:
> no chart name found'

with helm-controller logs as follows

> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-02-07T12:40:18.121Z","logger":"controller.helmrelease","msg":"***HelmChart 'flux-system/release-services-test-release-services' is not ready***","reconciler group":"helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io","reconciler kind":"HelmRelease","name":"release-services","namespace":"release-services-test"}
> {"level":"info","ts":"2022-02-07T12:40:18.135Z","logger":"controller.helmrelease","msg":"reconcilation finished in 15.458307ms, next run in 5m0s","reconciler group":"helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io","reconciler kind":"HelmRelease","name":"release-services","namespace":"release-services-test"}

Below is the HelmChart resource in AKS:

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: HelmChart
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-07T07:30:16Z"
  finalizers:
  - finalizers.fluxcd.io
  generation: 1
  name: release-services-test-release-services
  namespace: flux-system
  resourceVersion: "105266699"
  selfLink: /apis/source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1/namespaces/flux-system/helmcharts/release-services-test-release-services
  uid: e4820a70-8885-44a1-8dfd-0e2bf7256915
spec:
  chart: release-services
  interval: 5m0s
  reconcileStrategy: ChartVersion
  sourceRef:
    kind: HelmRepository
    name: psbombb-helm-acr-dev
  version: '>=0.1.0'
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-02-07T11:02:49Z"
    message: 'chart pull error: failed to get chart version for remote reference:
      no chart name found'
    reason: ChartPullFailed
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  observedGeneration: 1
```

and the HelmRelease is as follows

```
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-02-07T04:34:14Z"
  finalizers:
  - finalizers.fluxcd.io
  generation: 9
  labels:
    kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/name: apps
    kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/namespace: flux-system
  name: release-services
  namespace: release-services-test
  resourceVersion: "105341484"
  selfLink: /apis/helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1/namespaces/release-services-test/helmreleases/release-services
  uid: 6a6e5f5c-951d-4655-9c15-fa9fe7421a04
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: release-services
      reconcileStrategy: ChartVersion
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: psbombb-helm-acr-dev
        namespace: flux-system
      version: '>=0.1.0'
  install:
    remediation:
      retries: 3
  interval: 5m
  releaseName: release-services
  timeout: 12m
  values:
    image:
      name: release-services
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      registry: <repository>.azurecr.io
      repository: <repository>.azurecr.io/helm/release-services
      tag: 0.1.0
    postgres:
      secret:
        create: false
        existingName: release-services-secrets
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-02-07T08:27:13Z"
    message: HelmChart 'flux-system/release-services-test-release-services' is not
      ready
    reason: ArtifactFailed
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  failures: 50
  helmChart: flux-system/release-services-test-release-services
  observedGeneration: 9
```

Is there anything I am missing that anyone can spot for me please?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that the Azure Container Registry stores Helm Charts as OCI Artifacts.

The Flux source controller will pull the `index.yaml` from a HTTP Helm Chart repo to look for tags and this is not working with an OCI registry.

[Here](https://github.com/fluxcd/source-controller/issues/124) is the GitHub issue for this were you can see that the Flux guys will work on this as of now the OCI Feature is stable with Helm 3.8.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply Philip. You seem to be spot on as I came across this yesterday which seems to back what you are saying: 
https://fluxcd.io/docs/use-cases/azure/#helm-repositories-on-azure-container-registry -> 
"Newer ACR Helm documentation suggests using ACR as an experimental Helm OCI Registry. This will not work with Flux, because using Charts from OCI Registries is not yet supported."

Comment: What I ended up doing to work around this OCI issue was to push the Helm chart to the legacy ACR repository:

"az acr helm push --username <azure-client-id> --password <azure-client-secret> -n <acr-registry> release-services-0.1.0.tgz"

The chart references the Docker image pushed to the repository.